Can controller short circuit immobilizer
According to this post the short circuit on a can bus will not induct any failure: What happens if I shortcut the CANBUS?
Is it possible to make a immobiliser by short circuiting to ground the can bus? This way no one can talk on the bus. This approach is much easier than injecting packets on the bus in order to avoid ignition like common can bus based immobilizers. Let’s assume we have to deal with a keyless car like Alfa Romeo Giulia
